# PROC FREQ on multiple variables combined into one table

Tags: sas

I have the following problem. I need to run `PROC FREQ` on multiple variables, but I want the output to all be on the same table. Currently, a `PROC FREQ` statement with something like TABLES ERstatus Age Race, InsuranceStatus; will calculate frequencies for each variable and print them all on separate tables. I just want the data on ONE table.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I tried using `PROC TABULATE`, but it didn't not calculate N correctly, so I'm not sure what I did wrong. Here is my code for `PROC TABULATE`. My variables are all categorical, so I just need to know N and percentages.

```
PROC TABULATE DATA = BCanalysis;
CLASS ERstatus PRstatus Race TumorStage InsuranceStatus;
TABLE (ERstatus PRstatus Race TumorStage) * (N COLPCTN), InsuranceStatus;
RUN;
```

The above code does not return the correct frequencies based on InsuranceStatus where 0 = insured and 1 = uninsured, but `PROC FREQ` does. Also doesn't calculate correctly with ROWPCTN. So any way that I can get PROC FREQ to calculate multiple variables on one table, or PROC TABULATE to return the correct frequencies, would be appreciated.

Here is a nice image of my output in a simplified analysis of only ERstatus and InsuranceStatus. You can see that PROC FREQ returns 204 people with an ERstatus of 1 and InsuranceStatus of 1. That's correct. The values in PROC TABULATE are not.
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhCM9.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean a single SAS dataset, or a single printed-output-table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'll answer this separately as this is answering the other possible interpretation of the question; when it's clarified I'll delete one or the other.*

If you want this in a single *printed* table, then you either need to use `proc tabulate` or you need to normalize your data - meaning put it in the form of `variable | value`.  `PROC FREQ` is not capable of doing multiple one-way frequencies in a single table.

For `PROC TABULATE`, likely your issue is missing data.  Any variable that is on the `class` statement will be checked for missingness, and if any rows are missing data for any of the class variables, those rows are entirely excluded from the tabulation for *all* variables.

You can override this by adding the `missing` option on the `class` statement, or in the table statement, or in the `proc tabulate` statement.  So:

```
PROC TABULATE DATA = BCanalysis;
CLASS ERstatus PRstatus Race TumorStage InsuranceStatus/missing;
TABLE (ERstatus PRstatus Race TumorStage) * (N COLPCTN), InsuranceStatus;
RUN;
```

This will result in a slightly different appearance than on your table, though, as it will include the missing rows in places you probably *do not* want them, and they'll be factored against the `colpctn` when again you probably don't want them.

Typically some manipulation is then necessary; the easiest is to normalize your data and then run a tabulation (using `PROC TABULATE` or `PROC FREQ`, whichever is more appropriate; `TABULATE` has better percentaging options though) against that normalized dataset.

Let's say we have this:

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class; 
  if _n_=5 then call missing(age);
  if _n_=3 then call missing(sex);
run;
```

And we want these two tables in one table.

```
proc freq data=class;
  tables age sex;
run;
```

If we do this:

```
proc tabulate data=class;
  class age sex;
  tables (age sex),(N colpctn);
run;
```

Then we get an N=17 total for both subtables - that's not what we want, we want N=18.  Then we can do:

```
proc tabulate data=class;
  class age sex/missing;
  tables (age sex),(N colpctn);
run;
```

But that's not quite right either; I want F to have 8/18 = 44.44% and M 10/18 = 55.55%, not 42% and 53% with 5% allocated to the missing row.

The way I do this is to normalize the data.  This means you get a dataset with 2 variables, `varname` and `val`, or whatever makes sense for your data, plus whatever identifier/demographic/whatnot variables you might have.  `val` has to be character unless all of your values are numeric.

So for example here I normalize `class` with `age` and `sex` variables.  I don't keep any identifiers, but you certainly could in your data, I imagine `InsuranceStatus` would be kept there if I understand what you're doing in that table.  Once I have the normalized table, I just use those two variables, and carefully construct a denominator definition in `proc tabulate` to have the right basis for my `pctn` value.  It's not quite the same as the single table before - the variable name is in its own column, not on top of the list of values - but honestly that looks better in my opinion.

```
data class_norm;
  set class;
  length val $2;
  varname='age';
  val=put(age,2. -l);
  if not missing(age) then output;
  varname='sex';
  val=sex;
  if not missing(sex) then output;
  keep varname val;
run;


proc tabulate data=class_norm;
  class varname val;
  tables varname=' '*val=' ',n pctn<val>;
run;
```

If you want something better than this, you'll probably have to construct it in `proc report`.  That gives you the most flexibility, but is the most onerous to program in also.

Comment: This is really helpful. I haven't read the whole thing yet, just up to the part where you talked about missing data. I added a / MISSING statement to my PROC TABULATE and it generated the correct frequencies. But what's weird is, I don't know which data is missing. When I filter ERstatus = 1 and InsuranceStatus = 1 in MS Access, I come back with 204 records that have no missing data for those two columns. I will have to either finish reading your post or figure out where the missing info is that PROC TABULATE is finding, because it's not in ERstatus or InsuranceStatus columns.

Comment: By the way, I appreciate your help. I was hired as a clinical research assistant, but my boss saw I had a crap ton of math and statistics under my belt and SOME R and SAS skills, and now all I've been asked to do is run analysis in SAS, and I just don't have the skill level for it....yet. But I'm working real hard to improve, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it's missing in PRStatus or TumorStage or Race it will also affect the ERStatus table in PROC TABULATE.

Comment: Okay, I will go check. Thank you, Joe. Wish there was someone here at my company I could turn to, but I think I'm the only employee using SAS right now, ha!

Comment: So far, it's returning all the correct frequencies for Race, too. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you explain what this line of code means: val=put(age,2. -l);   and how varname and val can equal both sex and age. I must not be understanding that part right because in my head varname and val both equal age, then get overwritten by sex.  I've been trying to reproduce your example in SAS and this is where I'm stuck. Thanks!

Comment: `put(age,2. -l)` puts the age number into a 2 long character variable and left aligns it (so 6 becomes `"6 "` instead of `" 6"`).

Comment: Varname equals the string `"age"` while val contains the value that is stored in the variable `age`.  So if age=15, then `varname="age"` and `val="15"`.  Then we output that row.  Then we do it again with sex, and have a second row with `varname=sex; val='M';` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, Joe. Been really busy these past couple of days at work, so haven't had a chance to respond

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ODS OUTPUT` to get all of the PROC FREQ output to one dataset.

```
ods output onewayfreqs=class_freqs;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
  tables age sex;
run;
ods output close;
```

or

```
ods output crosstabfreqs=class_tabs;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
  tables sex*(height weight);
run;
ods output close;
```

`Crosstabfreqs` is the name of the cross-tab output, while one-way frequencies are `onewayfreqs`.  You can use `ods trace` to find out the name if you forget it.

You may (probably will) still need to manipulate this dataset some to get the structure you want ultimately.

Comment: This is a cut and paste answer from another website. It did not help me.

Comment: @lady8506 Err, that's an interesting statement, but I typed this in to the box entirely from my own knowledge - no cut and pasting for sure.  If this didn't help you, can you be more specific as to how it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: And just to be clear, this is the *only* way you could get this into a single table directly from PROC FREQ without either manipulating the original datafile (to be normalized) or manipulating the output results (to concatenate multiple datasets).  Which way you go about getting to a single dataset will depend on what you want the output to look like - you don't really explain that in your question.

Comment: If however you mean a single printed table, if you can clarify that in the OP that would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, let me be more clear on why it's not helping me. If I have 50 variables I need to run PROC FREQ on, I'm not understanding from your example whether or not I need to precede each PROC FREQ with an ODS OUTPUT statement, then proceed each PROC FREQ with an ODS OUTPUT CLOSE; statement. So basically,do I need to write PROC FREQ 50 times as well as the ODS OUTPUT statements 50 times? Second, when I use ODS OUTPUT on two separate PROC FREQs and then pull up the dataset I outputted it to, there is only one variable in the output dataset, the last one that was evaluated. There should be 2 vars.

Comment: If you have 50 variables then list them in the `tables` statement replacing the two variables, `age sex`, in the example code.